# Unchecked call error with generics and Java8 Streams

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I've got an odd warning from my IDE, but the code still runs fine.

The code is

```
class TaskQueue<T extends Comparable> {
    private final PriorityQueue<QueueItem<T>> queue = 
            new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(QueueItem::getDeadline));
}
```

The IDE gives me a warning and an error:

- **Warning**
  `Unchecked call to 'PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E>)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.PriorityQueue'`
- **Error** referring to `QueueItem::getDeadline`
  `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`

I'm new to Java and, altough the code works, I'd like to know if I can write it in a better way or if there is a proper way.

Thank you

### Edit

The code for `QueueItem`

```
class QueueItem<T extends Comparable>{
    private final T deadline;

    QueueItem(T deadline) {
        this.deadline = deadline;
    }


    T getDeadline() {
        return deadline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of `QueueItem` class?

Comment: my best guess will be getDeadline is not a static method. change it to static or use instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that `QueueItem` look a bit different(same goes for TaskQueue):

```
 QueueItem<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

notice the `T extends Comparable<T>`

Comparable is a generic type, but in your code you did not specify the type of that `Comparable`; instead it is raw.

Comment: That's it! I never thought about this feature.... But I had to modify it to `<T extends Comparable<? super T>> cause with your solution things like LocalDate don't work

Answer (score 1):

The method `QueueItem::getDeadline` return some kind of object that does not implement `Comparable`.

So the solution will be:

```
class Deadline implements Comparable<Deadline> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Deadline o) {
        return 0 /* Some comparing logic here */;
    }

}
```

And the `Comparator.comparing` expects something that returns `Comparable` object.